# ColdFusion pdf generated page numbering seems to have changed

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We recently upgraded from CF8 TO CF10, and an anomaly has raised it's head.
Whereas before, when I merged several documents together, the page numbering was contiguous, but now it starts anew at the beginning of each section.

So if I merge two 3-page documents, then I would get page numbers: 1,2,3,1,2,3.

Of course, it used to be: 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this remove the header and footer of merged PDF and  then add new new header and footer with page number

```
<cfpdf action="merge" source="1.pdf,2.pdf" destination="3.pdf"  >  
<cfpdf action="removeheaderfooter" source="3.pdf" destination="3.pdf" overwrite="yes" >
<cfpdf action="addheader" source="D:/Sites/cf9/3.pdf" text="_PAGENUMBER"
 destination="3.pdf" overwrite="yes" >
```

Comment: Thanks Keshav jha!  I've looked into it some more, and [house of fusion](http://house-of-fusion.10909.n7.nabble.com/CFPDF-Merge-Page-numbers-td12746.html) says it was reported in bug #83339, but I can't find it in the bug base to see its status.